# Pod not found: Could not find 'cocoapods' (>= 0) among 64 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)

Tags: cocoapods

After installing cocoapods with `sudo gem install cocoapods`, attempting to run `pod setup` returns this error:

```
Could not find 'cocoapods' (>= 0) among 64 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
```

Output from `sudo gem install cocoapods`:

```
CHANGELOG:

[CocoaPods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/compare/0.28.0...0.29.0)
• [CocoaPods-core](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Core/compare/0.28.0...0.29.0)
• [cocoapods-downloader](https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-downloader/compare/0.2.0...0.3.0)

[ bug/enhancement notes removed for brevity]

Successfully installed cocoapods-0.29.0
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-0.29.0
1 gem installed
```

When I list the gems installed, I do not see cocoapods listed among my Local Gems but I do see 'pod' listed in /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p0/bin.

System Configuration:

```
Mac OS 10.9 (upgraded from 10.8)
Xcode: 5.0.2 (upgrade from 4.x)
Ruby path: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p0
```

How can I get cocopods to work for me?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Uninstalling and reinstalling CocoaPods from the Terminal fixed the issue for me (see the [CocoaPods documentation](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html) for more information):

```
gem uninstall cocoapods
gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but I can't have write permission :  You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory

Comment: @GrayFox Use sudo in front of each instruction and normally the permission error should disappear.

Comment: sudo gem uninstall cocoapods 
sudo gem install cocoapods

Answer (score 16):

For me it was

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: For me it was 'gem install cocoapods' (without the sudo which caused problems)

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
sudo pod setup
```

Since you installed cocoapods as supervisor (sudo), there are files that supervisor can see that you can not.

This also means that after you add a pod to a podFile, you'll also need to run

```
sudo pod install
```

instead of

```
pod install
```

It ultimately might be better to undo the sudo install of cocoa pods and use [RVM](http://rvm.io/gemsets/basics).

With RVM you can have different versions of gem sets (including different versions of cocoapods, if required).  By going this route, you can then bypass having to run pod commands as sudo.

Comment: [!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root.

Comment: I'd say that one *shouldn't* run CocoaPods as root.  I strongly advise against it, but perhaps my words in my original response were too gentle.   I included : "It ultimately better to undo the sudo install of cocoa pods and use RVM".

Answer (score 1):

Simple do this thing write below thing in terminal..
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods

Answer (score -2):

you do not need to install cocapods using `sudo`

try:

```
gem install cocoapods
```

then:

```
pod
```

to check if it runs fine