# Pod setup cannot find cocoapods

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cocoapods

After installing cocoapods with sudo gem install cocoapods, attempting to run "pod setup" returns this error:

```
Could not find 'cocoapods' (>= 0) among 22 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
```

Output from "pod setup":

```
/Users/Kevin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:313:in `to_specs': Could not find 'cocoapods' (>= 0) among 22 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/Kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194:/Users/Kevin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /Users/Kevin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:322:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/Kevin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:53:in `gem'
    from /Users/Kevin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
```

When I check the directory listed in GEM_PATH, it includes:

```
...
drwxr-xr-x   5 root   staff   170B Jun 16 23:35 cocoapods-core-0.33.1/
drwxr-xr-x   5 Kevin  staff   170B Jun 16 23:41 cocoapods-downloader-0.6.1/
drwxr-xr-x  15 Kevin  staff   510B Jun 16 23:41 cocoapods-plugins-0.2.0/
drwxr-xr-x  11 Kevin  staff   374B Jun 16 23:41 cocoapods-trunk-0.1.3/
drwxr-xr-x  15 Kevin  staff   510B Jun 16 23:41 cocoapods-try-0.3.0/
...
```

So the files are there, though its core is root since I used `sudo gem install cocoapods`.

**Solutions suggested on previous Stack Overflow questions that I've tried:**

1. **Install cocoapods without sudo:** Suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986029/how-do-i-install-a-cocoa-pod-in-mavericks-with-ruby-and-command-line-tools-corre). However, even following these instructions I get permission denied when trying to use `gem install cocoapods`.
2. **Sudo pod setup**: Suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819564/pod-not-found-after-install-pod-setup-returns-could-not-find-cocoapods). However, `pod` tells me that I can't use it in sudo.
3. **Change permissions for cocoapods files**: Suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16049335/cocoapods-pod-install-permission-denied). I tried running the lines provided by the top answer but it says that those files do not exist.

How do I get `pod setup` to work?

Comment: Did you uninstall it with `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods` before trying to install again without `sudo`? Please read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23767092/3453503) again.

Comment: Thanks! Yup, I had tried that. For those with the same problem, I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling ruby which solved the problem for me--though may have been overkill.

Answer (score 22):

Don't use sudo.

```
1: sudo gem uninstall cocoapods 

2: gem install cocoapods

3: pod install
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. I solved it by

1. Removing cocoapods
2. Reinstalling it using `rvmsudo` instead of `sudo`
   `rvmsudo gem install cocoapods`

Hope it helps!

Comment: This answer was very helpful for me, because i believe i couldn't install pod as "sudo". Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

if your osx is 10.11 
use 
**sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin GEM_NAME_HERE**

Answer (score 1):

Run command rvm use system in Terminal,then the installation worked even though the system Ruby is 2.0.0.